# I don't understand the difference between these codes

Tags: python

```
data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9]

data.pop()
print(data)
```

result: `[2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10]`

the above is what i think makes sense

however,

```
data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9]

Print(data.pop())
```

I got this

Result : `9`

what is the difference?

Comment: It's worth look [at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). `pop()` alters the original list and *returns* the value. In one case you are printing the altered list, in the other you are printing the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st situation, you are printing a list of data. I have re-lined the code and added comments to make it more understandable:

**Scenario 1**:

```
data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9] # the given data list
data.pop() # pop the last element off the list
print(data) # print 'data' (which is the list)
```

The reason why the result here is [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10] is because you are popping from the list, and then printing the list itself.

**Scenario 2**:

```
data = [2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 10, 9] # the given data list
print(data.pop()) # print the value returned by data.pop(), which is 9

# Result : 9
```

`List.pop()` is a method that returns the popped value from the list. So, by doing `print(data.pop())`, you are requesting to print the single popped value rather than the `data` list in its entirety.

See the Python documentation on the `List.pop()` method [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Answer (score 0):

The pop() method returns the value which was deleted from the list.
If you try to print that d.pop() it just returns the removed value.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pop( ) it returns the last element of the list and internally it deletes last element from the list.

Note that in the first code you’re printing data ( the list )  and in the second one you’re printing what pop returns